# Writing and Reading virtual files on Windows

Tags: python, windows, file, subprocess, virtual-file

As part of a Python project on Windows, I need to use small files as a means to communicate different processes. Since the external process must be called with `subprocess.run(program, args...)`, I can't simply obtain a file descriptor for my file and pass it as a parameter to the external process. Instead, I need a file with a name which can be accessed from the normal filesystem. Thus, I would like a simple way to create a **temporary file which is stored in memory (RAM) instead of disk, and which has a name other external processes can use to access it.** In Linux, this can be achieved with the function `os.mkfifo()`. However, this function is not available in Windows.

At the moment, I am simply using the `tempfile` module to create a temporary file which is stored in disk and deleted once it is no longer needed. Here is a small reproducible example  for my code:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

fd = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+t", delete=False) # Obtain file descriptor
file_path = fd.name # Obtain file path

# Write data (encoded as str) to the file and close it
fd.write(data)
fd.close()

# Access this same file from an external process
output = subprocess.run( [program, file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')

# Delete the file
os.remove(file_path)

print("External process output:", output)
```

So, my question is the following: How can I change this code so that in line `fd.write(data)` the data is written to RAM instead of disk?

Comment: Python has no built-in support of a RAM disk. You might be able to use the [`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html?highlight=sharedmemory#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) class to do what you want. Each memory block is assigned a unique name, so the subprocesses can use that to access it.

Comment: @martineau I have taken a look at the documentation but I am unsure whether it works for my case. When I call `subprocess.run( [program, file_path] )`, the external program `program` expects as `file_path` the path of a file in the "normal" filesystem. From the `SharedMemory` documentation, it seems like the name assigned to the shared memory block could not be used as the argument `file_path` in my case. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, `SharedMemory` doesn't create a filesystem object so wouldn't be useful for running arbitrary programs that expect files to be passed to them.

Comment: Then, do you know of a workaround for my problem? An ideal solution would be to setup a virtual filesystem (RAM disk) on Windows, mount it as a new volume (e.g.: letter F:\) and save the data to a file located in such virtual filesystem. I think this can be easily done in Linux, not so sure about Windows...

Comment: Here's a free one I use [ImDisk Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/p/imdisk-toolkit/doc/Home/).

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. If you are sure there is no other solution to my problem on Python+Windows than mounting a RAM disk and then writing/reading files from it as "normal", then maybe you can post your comment as an answer to my question and I'll accept it. Although I don't know if that is the normal way to proceed in stackoverflow

Comment: I am sure Python and Windows have no built-in/native ways for creating RAM disks, and that ImDisk is one way to do so. If you try it and it works, you can post it as an answer to your own question (which *is* allowed here).